# c++ : Static initialization with private constructor

Tags: c++

When I was learning the singleton pattern, I saw that the constructor is private, so can static class member variables still be initialized with new()?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A{
public:
    static A* getInstance(){
        return aa;
    }
    void setup(){
        cout<<"inside setup!"<<endl;
    }
private:
    static A* aa;
    A(){
        cout<<"constructor called!"<<endl;
    }
};
A* A::aa = new A;   //  <== How to explain this sentence ???                                                                                    

int main()
{
    A* aa1 = A::getInstance();
    A* aa2 = A::getInstance();

    if(aa1 == aa2)
        cout<<"Yes"<<endl;
    else
        cout<<"No"<<endl;
    cout << "Hello world!"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the [C++11 standard](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3690.pdf), specifically in 9.4.2 [class.static.data]:

> 2. [...] The initializer expression in the definition of a static data member is in the scope of its class [...]

So the reason why you are able to do

```cpp
A* A::aa = new A;
```

from "outside" the class declaration, is because `new A` (the initializer expression) is performed in the scope of `A`, and therefore has access to all private, protected and public identifiers of that class, including the private constructor.

---

As a note, please rethink your singleton design. Your class is not properly destroyed, can be copied/moved and returns a pointer for no good reason. Consider using something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1008289/4184203), instead.

Also, please avoid [`using namespace std`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).